Deform a flat object/wire on the surface of an irregular object

I modeled this sort of wire outline - that was a bezier curve that I added depth to - that's on top of the bulb-shaped object, and I want to make it be on the surface of the bulb as if you drew it on with a pencil and then carved it out.
I tried moving each individual vertex onto the bulb but they don't line up with the mesh of the bulb so there are parts of the wire that get 'submerged' in the mesh.
I've also tried to follow some solutions to similar questions but those didn't work with the odd-shaped bulb from what I've tried.
I also have a version from when it was still a bezier curve that wasn't converted to a mesh if that would be easier to work with.

Hello could you please share your file?

When you cannot even manually fit it on the surface and parts get submerged, I suspect you do not have enough geometry to perform this task. When placing two connected vertices on a surface, their edge is a straight line (mesh edges between two vertices are always straight), if the surface inbetween is curved you need more vertices to follow that shape. When you have a Bézier curve instead of a mesh, the connecting segment between control points is not necessarily straight (depending on your curve's resolution), but then you have to adjust the handles to make the curve fit the surface.

you could e.g. use a shrinkwrap modifier and a geometry nodes modifier like this:

The GN modifier converts the mesh to curve and and back to mesh with a circle profile.

the shrinkwrap modifiers moves your wire to your surface (i choose project here, of course this does not work, if you wanna wrap your wire all around your object), and the GN modifier gives your wire the thickness.

You should use an offset which "fits" to your radius of your curve circle node.

thanks, this worked! the geometry nodes really helped, its a solution I wouldn't have thought of but now in the future maybe I will

glad i could help
